# Why is mov 0900h, ax allowed in emu8086?

Tags: x86-16, emu8086

I just checked the manual again and MOV Immediate, REG is not allowed and in fact is illogical, but when I compile, it runs just fine.

Comment: Have you also checked the actual code generated, what machine instruction was actually deployed there ( disassembly view )?

Comment: @user3666197 No I am sadly a beginner. I don't like being spoon fed so I will look further into disassembly view right away. Thank you very much for the guidance :)

Comment: This is an oddity in EMU8086. When the destination is an immediate it assumes that you meant a memory operand so it will assume 0900h is `[ds:0900h]` . EMU8086 would have probably translated your instruction to `mov [ds:0900h], ax` or equivalent.

Comment: I just read the debug logs and saw this line MOV [00900h], AX, it all makes sense now. Thank you very much @MichaelPetch.

Comment: Yes, a piece of a first-hand experience **:o)**

Comment: @MichaelPetch please post you answer as an answer. This is a recurring, practical problem, a perfect fit for SO.

Comment: You can self answer your own question, please be my guest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction **MOV immediate value, REG** is invalid but emu8086 corrects for this case. Instead of considering 0900h in MOV 0900h, ax as an immediate value, it marks 0900h as **[DS:0900h]** which represents a certain memory location.